# how to download archive in aws s3 glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

first, sorry for my bad english.
i create a vault in glacier service and then i uploaded an archive into vault and in out-put, aws gave back me a archive id. then using the archive-id, i created a job for downloading using this command:

```
aws glacier initiate-job --account-id - --vault-name <example-vault-name> --job-parameters file://<created-json-file-using-aws-documentation>.json
```

after that, aws returned to me a location and job id. like this:

```
{
"location": "/1123213213131/vaults/<example-vault-name>/jobs/<some-string>",
"jobId": "<some-string>"
}
```

and then after than 3-5 hour, running this command:

```
aws glacier get-job-output --account-id - --vault-name <example-vault-name> --job-id <job-id> output.json
```

and the out-put above command. like this:

```
{
"checksum": "<some-string>",
"status": 200,
"acceptRanges": "bytes",
"contentType": "application/octet-stream",
"archiveDescription": "<uploaded-file-name>.zip"
}
```

and my question is a, now, how can i download the .zip ???

Answer (score 0):

In the <output.json> field, you should write uploaded file name. if the uploaded file name you want retrive, is a: backup.zip, you should run your command like this:

```
aws glacier get-job-output --account-id - --vault-name <example-vault-name> --job-id <job-id> backup.zip
```

at the end, the backup.zip in your system. you can verify the downloaded file checksum, using the response checksum.